# Creating white fade in and out between QT Movies for Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa, qt, macos, qtkit

I'm trying to achieve a certain effect in Cocoa application. I have several QT movies and a window with buttons that each link to a different movie, and play that movie in the main window. Pretty simple. The problem is I'd like to have a white fade come in and out (more of a flash, really) when the main window switches movies. I'm stuck on how to proceed. I noticed that there is a library for Cocoa called Core Image which can supposedly be used to create visual effects for movies, but is that the best way to proceed? Or is there a simpler way in the QTKit? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just figured this out. I can adjust the alpha levels--> [Change Alpha on Main Window - Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448931/change-alpha-on-main-window-cocoa)